# Google Sheets: Those rows are out of bounds, can't figure out why

Tags: javascript

I've been piecing together a script to delete empty rows from a specific tab in a series of spreadsheets.  It works up until the point it has to delete the rows, throwing a *Those rows are out of bounds* error.  I followed this technique to delete the rows, which seems to have good results for others, so I'm having trouble figuring out why this isn't working.

I thought maybe it was that I was exceeding the number of deletable rows by 1, but tested that, and it didn't make a difference.

Any ideas? Thanks for the input!

```
function myFunction() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange(2,3,17);
var values = range.getValues();

for (var row in values){
 for (var col in values[row]) {
  var theUrl = values[row][col];
  var openTheUrl = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(theUrl);
  Logger.log(openTheUrl.getName());

  var currentSheet = openTheUrl.getSheetByName("Aggregate");
  Logger.log(currentSheet.getName());

  var maxRows = currentSheet.getMaxRows(); 
  var lastRow = currentSheet.getLastRow();
  var deleteRows = maxRows-lastRow;

  if (maxRows-lastRow != 0){
  sheet.deleteRows(lastRow+1, deleteRows);
  }
 }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, I can understand as follows.

- You want to delete rows using `maxRows` and `lastRow` retrieved from `currentSheet` opened by `theUrl`.
- The rows that you want delete is in `currentSheet`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From :

```
sheet.deleteRows(lastRow+1, deleteRows);
```

#### To :

```
currentSheet.deleteRows(lastRow+1, deleteRows);
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thats it!  Wow, that was a dumb mistake on my part.  Today I learned a lesson to double check variable names.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jeremy Chance I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.